# Microsoft password bypass

Tags: passwords

I have a computer tower that is Microsoft Windows 7 or 8, I think. It came from a deceased family member. I'd like to pull pictures off of the computer for his memorial, but it has a password on the start screen. How can I bypass that without losing files?

Comment: Typically the computer won't have any full disk encryption. You can remove the hard-drive, load into onto a separate computer and copy it from there. Or you can boot into the computer from a USB/CD with a flavour of Linux, and use that to browse the files -- this is all presuming they haven't done something like bitlocker.

Comment: Well, even if it is encrypted, doing the above is the fastest way to either retrieve it or to know whether it is drive encrypted. At the same time, if your goal is simply pictures for a memorial, wouldn't Facebook or Instagram be better? Digging through a personal computer for pictures is... well, risky. You may not want to see what pictures they have saved.

Comment: Considering they are deceased and presuming of natural causes, there's a higher likelihood they don't embrace or personally utilize cloud storage, and particularly for personal media.  Digging around to find which service, if any, they might happen to use is not much more practical, if not *less* so.  Speaking from personal experience, I work at a company where the senior management still prefers fax over e-mail and still enforces mandatory and handwritten double-entry bookkeeping alongside our ERP.

Answer (score 3):

As @keithRozario mentioned, use a Linux CD (or USB). [Example, here](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-windows-password-with-linux-boot-cd.html).
Remember, you don't get the password, you RESET it.
Note: you have to make sure that the PC boots from CD (or USB). So, you might need to go into the BIOS and change the boot order. [Read this](http://www.boot-disk.com/boot_priority.htm) for more.

Comment: This is usefull if you trying to **run** the system you're breaking into. If you are only looking to extract files, you're much better off just reading the files directly from another computer instead of actively modifying the drive. See  "keithRozario" comment.